# How to design a web app that run a long-running script on changeable user input?

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

**Description:**

I am designing a web-scraping web app that takes in user input(mostly urls with its item_id), pipe it to my web-scraping script, saved the data scraped from webpage into database. **I am using flask, python and mysql**.

**Problems:**

Now, an user may upload some urls with item_id in csv and then later want to change some url for reasons that, well, maybe they find a mismatch between an item and its url,in which case I have offered a web form with item_id and url as inputs for end-user to upload their new url with its item_id.

The problem is that when an user uploads a large csv file at first, I would start a thread to run web-scraping script on the inputs and saving scraped data in database, which should take rather long because of the size of the input. And later when user upload some change of urls, I would start a thread again to run the same web-scraping script on these smaller input, which should take a much shorter amount of time than the first run. This way, the second run would end and save data in my database only to be overwritten by the first and slower run.

**Desired Result:**

The ultimate goal is to manage the data input properly so that the later uploaded urls would be used, and data on those page should be stored in my database.

**What I am getting instead:**

Later uploaded urls are used, and write data into database but then overwritten by the data from the previously uploaded and wrong urls.

**My thoughts:**

1. Maybe I can make sure that the second run will be run only after the first run finishes. But I am using python thread to take in user input and run my script. And threads does not work that way.
2. Instead of running script on user input, maybe I can build a database layer on top of my app, and when an user upload some new data, I pipe it to the database. And somehow let my script listening on the change in database tables, and run script on those changes. But I have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and run the thread as a celery task. Each time you run a new celery task, you store the task id and the user in a database. Then when you are making a second run you can wait for the first task to end:

```
@app.task()
def celery_task(user):
    first_task_id = get_first_task_id(user)  # Get id from the db
    if first_task_id is not None:  # First task is still running
        app.AsyncResult(first_task_id).get()

    # Do your second operation
    # Remove task_id from db
```